# Trying to access database with jboss esb and java

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jboss, jndi

I have a problem to get connection to my database via java and jboss esb 4.2. I have build a .war package and deployed it on the jboss server. But i am gettin error while trying to connect to the database.

**Java Method**

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
    Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/VINService");

    String sql = "SELECT ...";
    conn = ds.getConnection();
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
...
```

**jboss-web.xml**

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/VINService</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>java:jdbc/VINService</jndi-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
</resource-ref>
```

**web.xml**

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>VINService</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/VINService</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

**VIN_Service-ds.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>
   <local-tx-datasource>
      <jndi-name>jdbc/VINService</jndi-name>
      <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://url/db?autoReconnect=true</connection-url>
      <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
      <user-name>name</user-name>
      <password>password</password>
      <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
      <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
      <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
      <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
      <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1 FROM vehiclecache limit 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

What am i doing wrong? I am getting Nullpointer Error at

> conn = ds.getConnection()

so it isn't finding the datasource. 
Can anybody help me?

Comment: It's simple If you getting Nullpointer Error at conn = ds.getConnection(); , This means this method **ds.getConnection()** returns **null**, Don't doubt on JVM

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459465/how-can-we-configure-database-connection-from-jboss

Comment: But why is it null? I have configured it and my database is accessable.

Comment: <jndi-name>jdbc/VINService</jndi-name> and check above link

Comment: I checked the link and i did the things! Doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you go through this by these step https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7?_sscc=t

 It will must resolve you Connection issue.

Comment: But i have not JBossAS7. I have JBoss ESB 4.2

Comment: JBossESB is the next generation of EAI But This is not the issue, Java use common configuration to connect with any database. http://www.mastertheboss.com/soa-cloud/jboss-soa/jboss-esb-tutorial?start=1